# TerminateProcess not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, process, windows-7-x64

I am writing an application in c++ on win7 platform which needs to close another application.
The steps I use are:

1. Enumerate all processes with EnumProcess().
2. Open a Process handle with OpenProcess(). The access rights are PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS|PROCESS_VM_READ.
3. Then enumerate process modules with EnumProcessModules()
4. I extract the module name with GetModuleBaseName() and compare it with the process name that I have.
5. When I find a match, I use TerminateProcess() to kill the process.

The problem I am facing is this works in WindowsXP but not in Windows 7(64 bit). Using getlasterror(),
I get the error as "Access Denied". I guess it has something to do with access rights.
Is there any way I can do this on both the platforms? Or is there an API specific to win7?

Comment: I suppose you've already ruled out the possibility of simply sending a [`WM_QUIT` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632641.aspx) to that other application?

Comment: or WM_CLOSE to the main window?

Comment: Hey, After changing the permissions and debugging some more, I finally figured out the problem. It seems that EnumProcessModules fails because I am trying to enumerate modules of a 64bit process from a 32- bit process. The error code is 299. I needed EnumProcessModules to find the pid of the process with a given name in a platform independent way (win7/winxp etc, only windows). And I am not able to find anything besides using the system command.

Yes I tried the WM_QUIT, but the problem remains the same here. I am not able to find the pid of a process with a given name.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Been looking very long for an answer and finally found it.

When you want to terminate another program you need a handle. A handle needs permissions to work with the other process. Terminating the process needs a specific permissions called `PROCESS_TERMINATE`. Use that when opening a handle for termination and it will probably work. It did for me, on Windows 7.

To sum things up, here the code you need to correctly use `TerminateProcess`. Handle with care ;)

```
Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
    ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
    ByVal dwProcessID As Long) As Long
Declare Function TerminateProcess Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal ApphProcess As Long, _
    ByVal uExitCode As Long) As Long

Const PROCESS_TERMINATE = &H1

Private Sub KillProcess(ByVal ProcessID As Long)
    Dim pHandle As Long
    pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, ProcessID)
    Call TerminateProcess(pHandle, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your program with Administrator privileges, and are you terminating processed of the same user?

Comment: I need to digg up this old question because i have similar problems. I want to use TerminateProcess to kill a 32 bit process. Both applications are started by the same user and that user has administrator privileges. I have tried adding a manifest to get higher privileges but i didn't work. If anyone can get the TerminateProcess function to work on Windows 7, please let me now how.